# C# Login to a non-interactive website and pass XML via URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webrequest

Okay, so here is what I have and I am probably doing this completely wrong, but I need some more direction than what I am finding online.

I am trying to pass a URL containing login information and then pass another url in the same connection containing my XML. That's all, and I can't seem to get this to work.  Please help!!

Here's my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace DataIntegration.DataSender
{
class RaveDataSender
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri(@"https://api.myloginpage.com/edc_studyservices.jsp?action=importfile&filecontents=<?xml version='1.0'?><dataprocessitems><item>someitem</item></dataprocessitems>&filename=1.xml");
        System.Uri loginUri = new System.Uri(@"https://api.myloginpage.com/login.jsp?studyid=something&action=login&login=myLoginName&password=myPassword");
        byte[] mybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("https://api.myloginpage.com/edc_studyservices.jsp?action=importfile&filecontents=<?xml version='1.0'?><dataprocessitems><item>someitem</item></dataprocessitems>&filename=1.xml");
        byte[] loginbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(@"https://api.myloginpage.com/login.jsp?studyid=something&action=login&login=myLoginName&password=myPassword");
        CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient();

        client.UploadDataAsync(loginUri, loginbytes);
        client.UploadDataAsync(myUri, mybytes);

        client.Dispose();


    }

    public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }


    }
}
```

EDIT this is what I ended up doing.

```
 using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient()) 
        {
            byte[] authresp = client.UploadData(loginUri, loginbytes);
            byte[] dataRespose = client.UploadData(xmlUri, reqbytes);

            string authResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(authresp);
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataRespose);
            client.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: so side question here, are you passing usernames and password in clear text..? wow I would not do that .. if you have a web app that has a login page, handle the redirects from there once you validate don't store that type of information in a URL

Comment: Thanks for noticing that.  Obviously the values here are not real.  Fortunately this is the spec that was given and how I have been instructed to handle this integration.  But yeah, you're preachin to the choir here.

Comment: wow that's not a good approach.. perhaps they are not aware of what doing it this way could expose themselves to...

Comment: `client.Dispose()` - don't do that... not until your upload is complete... override the event handler `UploadDataCompleted` and dispose the client there if you really want to. Otherwise just hold on to that fella until you're really, really done (disposes can be expensive, LOL)

Comment: okay, so I changed the client.UploadDataAsync to a client.UploadData and that resolved the issue.  I also found out that the actual client had not given my account write access so it may have been working before and I would have never known.  Thanks for your help. If you post your answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you dispose the object while the asynchronous methods still running.